# Find the formula and eigenvalues for $\overbrace{\operatorname{adj}\dots \operatorname{adj}}^{k}(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My attempts  :   i know that  if  $A$ is invertible then  it has  eigenvalue  $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$,......$\lambda_n$

as here im confused  that  how  can  i find the  Formula and eigenvalue  of adj A

Pliz help me.......im very confused

thanks  in Advance.....

thanks u

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks  u

Comment: $A\operatorname{adj}(A)=|A|I$. Now $|A|=1$. So, the relationship between $A$ and $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please don't use pictures to ask questions. Some people cannot view them on some devices and it's difficult to search for an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laplace's formula gives us $A\cdot\mathrm{adj}\ A = \mathrm{det}\ A\cdot\ I$. If $\mathrm{det}(A) = 1$, then this gives us $A\cdot\mathrm{adj}\ A = I,\ \mathrm{adj}\ A = A^{-1}.$

That would give you $\overbrace{\mathrm{adj\ adj\ \cdots\ adj}}^{k\ \mathrm{times}}\ A$ = $A$ if $k$ is even, $A^{-1}$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: The question is about the Eigenvalues.

Comment: And the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are ... ?

Comment: This is precisely what the OP ignores. At best you gave a partial hint.

Comment: im not getting @Kevin Kenny,,,,How  comes  $A^{-1} $ when  K is  odd ?? i thinks its  should be  both  A when k is odd and even

Comment: If $\text{adj}(A) = A^{-1}$ then $ \text{adj(adj}(A)) = \text{adj}(A^{-1}) = (A^{-1})^{-1} = A$ and reiterate. From the first two you can see that if you apply the adjoint one time you get the inverse, two time you get $A$ again. This clearly shows you that is you apply the adjoint $k$-times with $k$ odd, you get the inverse, if $k$ is even you get $A$

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Using the fact that $A\cdot\text{adj}(A) = |A|I$ if $|A|=1$ we have that **the adjoint matrix of $A$ is the inverse $A^{-1}$** so, if $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_n$, what are the eigenvalues of $A^{-1} = \text{adj}(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is diagonalizable,

$$A=P\Lambda P^{-1}.$$

Then

$$\frac{\text{adj}(A)}{\det(A)}A=A^{-1}A=P\Lambda ^{-1}P^{-1}P\Lambda P^{-1}=PD^{-1}\Lambda P^{-1}=I$$

which implies

$$\Lambda ^{-1}\Lambda =I.$$

As the product of two diagonal matrices is the diagonal matrix with the pairwise products, the Eigenvalues of the inverse (and the adjoint) of $A$ are the inverses of the Eigenvalues of $A$.

Finally, the Eigenvalues of the adjoint of $A$ taken $k$ times are the inverses of the Eigenvalues or the Eigenvalues themselves, depending on the parity of $k$.